# Big-O Complexity of Two Problems

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I was practicing a few Big-O complexity problems for one of my classes and these two problems seem to stump me the most.

For both of these, I need to determine the best and worst-case complexity.

Q1

```
function FUNC3(int array[n], int n, int key)
    int i = 1;
    while (i < n) do {
        if (key == array[0]) then
            i = i + n^0.25;
        else
            i = i + n^0.5;
    }
```

The best-case I got was: O(n / n^0.5) while my worst-case was: O(n / n^0.25)

Q2

```
function FUNC4(int array[n], int n, int key)
    for (int i=1; i<n; i = i * 2) do
        for (int j=0; j<sqrt(n); j++) do {
            if(array[0] == key) then {
                int k = 1;
                while (k < n) do
                    k = k * sqrt(n);
            }
        }
```

For this one, I got best-case: O(logn x sqrt(n)), with a worst-case of: O(logn x n)

Although, I am not very confident in these answers, do any of these look about right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's visit each of these individually. Here's your first function:

```
function FUNC3(int array[n], int n, int key)
    int i = 1;
    while (i < n) do {
        if (key == array[0]) then
            i = i + n^0.25;
        else
            i = i + n^0.5;
    }
```

You are correct that the best-case runtime is Θ(n / n<sup>0.5</sup>) and that the worst case is Θ(n / n<sup>0.25</sup>). It might help to rewrite these by simplifying the exponents; the first runtime is

> Θ(n / n<sup>0.5</sup>) = Θ(n<sup>0.5</sup>) = Θ(√n)

and the second runtime is

> Θ(n / n<sup>0.25</sup>) = Θ(n<sup>3/4</sup>).

Now, let's look at the second function:

```
function FUNC4(int array[n], int n, int key)
    for (int i=1; i<n; i = i * 2) do
        for (int j=0; j<sqrt(n); j++) do {
            if(array[0] == key) then {
                int k = 1;
                while (k < n) do
                    k = k * sqrt(n);
            }
        }
```

To determine the runtime, let's use the time-honored maxim

> "When in doubt, work inside out!"

Let's begin with the innermost loop:

```
int k = 1;
while (k < n) do
    k = k * sqrt(n);
```

This loop is sneaky - it never runs more than three times because the values of k will be 1, then √n, then n. This means that the loop does O(1) total work. As a result, we can rewrite the overall code as

```
function FUNC4(int array[n], int n, int key)
    for (int i=1; i<n; i = i * 2) do
        for (int j=0; j<sqrt(n); j++) do {
            if(array[0] == key) then {
                do O(1) work;
            }
        }
```

Since the `if` statement does O(1) work regardless of whether it executes, we're left with

```
function FUNC4(int array[n], int n, int key)
    for (int i=1; i<n; i = i * 2) do
        for (int j=0; j<sqrt(n); j++) do {
            do O(1) work;
        }
```

If we do O(1) work √n times, then the runtime is Θ(√n), so the inner loop becomes

```
function FUNC4(int array[n], int n, int key)
    for (int i=1; i<n; i = i * 2) do
        do sqrt(n) work
```

Since the work done in the inner loop is independent of the value of `i`, the work done here is simply the product of the number of outer loop iterations and the work done by one iteration. The outer loop runs Θ(log n) times, so the work here is Θ(√n log n), regardless of the array contents. So that makes the best- and worst-case runtimes for the function the same, since the total work done is (asymptotically) always the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a very big help! My only question is that, the loop in the if statement (for FUNC4) wouldn't that execute at a complexity of O(sqrt(n)) because k has to multiply itself by sqrt(n) everytime it iterates through the while loop? I don't think that's a linear problem, which would make it O(1). That's how I got my worst-case of O(logn*sqrt(n)*sqrt(n)) = O(logn*n)

Comment: Ah, I re-read your reasoning more and it makes sense because it will probably only run 2-3 times, that makes it a linear complexity, right?

Comment: Since the loop only runs a fixed number of times, the complexity of that loop is O(1). It would be similar to a for loop that counted from 1 to 3 - the complexity is O(1) because there's no dependence on the size of the array.